# iTunes music API for accessing user's play history

Tags: ios, media-player, itunes

I know I can use MPMediaQuery to query songs on the device, and from there I can get play counts from MPMediaItem. This is good, but assume that the user played a song 100 times on their computer and did not sync this song to their device. Is there an API outside the iOS SDK that allows me to retrieve a user's play history from their iTunes account? I assume the answer is no, but just wanted to make sure there are no other ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no way you could retrieve a user's play history from their iTunes account.